# Get property from parent control of template via triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have next XAML

```
<ComboBox Margin="5" Width="150" Name="languageComboBox">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Russian" Tag ="1" IsSelected="True"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="English" Tag="2"/>
</ComboBox>   

<DataGrid Name="VulnersDatagrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Заголовок" Width="*" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="Vulner.DefaultDescription.Title">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Name="testTextBox" Margin="5,0" Text="My example Text" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How with using triggers i can change text in testTextBox in each row to text from languageComboBox when i change selected item in languageComboBox?

**UPDATE: ATTANTION!** ComboBox and TextBlock are in diferent DataTemplates, so that standart solution like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=languageComboBox, Path=SelectedValue.Content}" Name="testTextBox" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Dosnot work!

Comment: Привет, Сергей! Not exactly an answer, but why not to move all logic to code-behind (to ViewModel if you`re using MVVM)? You can have properties that contain collection of languages and selected language, and bind anything you want to them.
Is there a reason to struggle trying to fit that functionality in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, got it working by adding a property and binding to the ancestor (in my case window).

Property in viewmodel:

```
    public object SelectedValue
    {
        get { return _selectedValue; }
        set 
        { 
            _selectedValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedValue");
        }
    }
    private object _selectedValue;
```

Binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue.Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

Comment: Yes, i found this solution before, but senk you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind it:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=languageComboBox, Path=SelectedValue.Content}" Name="testTextBox" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: No, it's dos not work, becouse TextBlock and ComboBox are in diferent DataTemplates, and if i do that - brogram will not compiled with error "can't find languageComboBox".